# Can I do a multiseat having only an integrated and a dedicated graphic card?

Tags: multiseat

My laptop has 2 video cards:

With `lspci -nn | grep '\[03` I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
0a:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

Can I do a multiseat with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use multiseat the graphics card you can use for it need to be shown in the output of `lspci`. If you have both the integrated and the dedicated card in it at the same time you can use both. So yes.

- Mind though that some systems do not allow you to use both (the card you can pick in BIOS but only one at a time).
- There is also: [xephyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr).